# Django, make model that refer more than equal 2 foreign key but not be deleted CASCADE

Tags: python, django

I have django model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class TestModel(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    def __str__(self):
        return "TestModel %s" % self.description


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class TestModelLog(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    foreignkey = models.ForeignKey(TestModel_2, related_name='test_foreignkey_1', null=True, blank=True)
    foreignkey_2 = models.ForeignKey(TestModel_2, related_name='test_foreignkey_2', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "TestModelLog %s" % self.description
```

Let say I made a model object like this:

- testmodel_a = TestModel.object.get_or_create(descripton=A_test)
- testmodel_b = TestModel.object.get_or_create(descripton=B_test)
- testmodel_log = TestModelLog.object.get_or_create(descripton=Log, foreignkey=testmodel_a, foreignkey=testmodel_b)

Although I set `null=True, blank=True` to `TestModelLog`'s `foreignKey` fields in models.py, not `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, When I try to delete just  `testmodel_a`(or `testmodel_b`) in django admin, it keep saying it will delete related `testmodel_log` also.

I thought `testmodel_log` will still be exist whether `testmodel_a` or `testmodel_b` is deleted or not.

**Question:** 
Why this happened and How to make `testmodel_log` be independent from `testmodel_a` or `testmodel_b`'s change?

**Edit**
What I exactly want is like if `testmodel_a` is deleted,

```
>>>result = testmodel_log.object.get(foreign_key2=testmodel_b)
>>>print(type(result.foreignkey))
>>>None
>>>print(result.description)
>>>Log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this and dont forget to migrate after makemigrations

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class TestModelLog(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    foreignkey = models.ForeignKey(TestModel_2, related_name='test_foreignkey_1', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING ,null=True, blank=True)
    foreignkey_2 = models.ForeignKey(TestModel_2, related_name='test_foreignkey_2',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "TestModelLog %s" % self.description
```

Comment: Thanks Exprator, You saved me

Comment: glad could help @touchingtwist

Comment: I have a question, would you let me know it? If I delete testmodel_a, What value will take testmodel_log's foreignkey field? null? or something? How blank=True option be shown this case? Sorry for more question.

Comment: as null=True in your field it will be null after the foreign table is deleted

Comment: So, what if being without null=True?

Comment: it will be blank

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are very nice